# Sample codeC++: Do all the objects within a larger object get deleted by calling delete on larger object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673998/what-is-difference-between-instantiating-an-object-using-new-vs-without) answer explains that what happens when we create/remove object with and without ***new/delete***. Now consider three object ***top, mid*** and ***bottom***.
***top*** is created WITHOUT ***new***, and it goes out of scope only when whole program ends. Now within ***top*** there is and infinite while loop which keep creating and deleting ***mid*** objects by using ***new*** and ***delete***. And on creation ***mid*** objects create some ***bottom*** objects within them, WITHOUT ***new***, which are never deleted explicitly.

My question is, will bottom objects be automatically deleted on ***delete*** call on ***mid***?
It seems scope of ***bottom*** is in whole top. So every created ***bottom*** object will never go out of scope. Right?

Sample Code:

```
Main:
    Top();

Top.h:
    class Top{
        public:        
            vector<Mid> midVec;
    }

Top::Top(){
    canExit = false;
    run();
}
Top::run(){
    while(!canExit){
        //dosomething
        midVec.push_back(new Mid(););
        //againdosomemorething - they use Mid and things within it.

        vector<Mid>::iterator b, e;
        //iterate over midVec check for some condition and identify some to delete.
        // call ***delete*** on identified objects.

    }
}


Mid::Mid(){
    for(int i =0; i<someCount; i++){
        Bottom obj = Bottom();
        umB.insert(std::make_pair<int, Bottom>(i, obj));
        umBPTR.insert(std::make_pair<int, Bottom*>(i, &obj));
    } 

}

Mid.h
    class Mid{
    public:
        unordered_map<int, Bottom> umB;
        unordered_map<int, Bottom*> umBPTR;
    }
```

Comment: The answer would depend on details you haven't told us.  It would be best if you presented a complete, fully compilable and runnable test program and asked whether it has a memory leak or not.

Comment: 1. Agree with zwol, give Your code. 2. In very short: probably You need (good designed) DESTRUCTOR

Comment: @zwol Done added sample code.

Comment: @JacekCz Done added sample code.

Comment: better to provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code, and you may need to learn more about scope in c++.

Comment: This code is unusable, cant compile etc. BTW visible fragments are without understanding basic ideas of OOP and C++ (variables in construtor)

Comment: your "bottom" objects in the unordered map will be deleted after the constructor finishes. Their scope is the body of the `Mid` constructor.

Comment: @Noidea corrected. They are actually declared in H files.